# alert -1 instead of their respective counter inside of the loop?

Tags: javascript, jscript

Why do the anchors, when clicked on, alert `-1` instead of their respective counter inside of the loop? How can you fix the code so that it does alert the right number?

```
<a href="#">text</a><br><a href="#">link</a>
<script>
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for ( var i = as.length; i--; ) {
    as[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(i);
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This question is from an online coding test, I'm pretty sure it's against the spirit of the test to make the answer so easily Google-able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a closure problem: every anonymous function you define inside your loop reads the value of "i" at the end of the for loop.

You need another scope, for example calling a function that sets the onclick handler.

```
function add_onclick(el, i) {
    el.onclick = function() {
        alert(i);
        return false;
    }
}

var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for ( var i = as.length; i--; ) {
    add_onclick(as[i],i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to achieve the same result as [Keeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20459914/1615483) is to use a function expression for the closure, which you immediately invoke, using your value as a parameter to create the closure

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for ( var i = as.length; i--; ) (function (i) {
    as[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(i);
        return false;
    }
}(i));
```

This way requires minimal code refactoring

Comment: @downvoter, please comment so I might address the issue you have with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the value of variable `i`. After the loop, it's value is `-1`.